# How can i change the container by hovering on the content

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to know how to change the container by hovering on the content

```css
.container {
   width:100vw;
   height:100vh;
}
.content:hover .container {
   background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background: red;
}    
.container:hover{
    background: white;
}
```